# Double Matching of two columns in a data frame

Tags: r, matching

```
library(data.table)
data <- setDT(data.frame(name=c(NA, "bob1", "bob", "jack", "bob1", "bob"), ID=c(1,1,4,3,2,1)))

     name   ID 
1:    NA     1    
2:    bob1   1    
3:    bob    4   
4:    jack   3
5:    bob1   2
6:    bob    1
```

Matching Criteria (at the same time):

- If different names have the same ID, change the names to a unique name
- If different ID have the same names, change the IDs to a unique ID

Desired output:

```
     name   ID 
1:    bob    1    
2:    bob    1    
3:    bob    1   
4:    jack   3
5:    bob    1
6:    bob    1
```

or

```
     name   ID 
1:    bob1   1    
2:    bob1   1    
3:    bob1   1   
4:    jack   3
5:    bob1   1
6:    bob1   1
```

Comment: What criteria should be used to select the most appropriate value from any conflicting names?

Comment: Any name is fine. That is why I have noted two possible outcomes. Having a unique name is important.

Comment: `bob 1 jack 1 jack 2` would be ambiguous

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, yes you are correct. But, what if there is no such a situation. I am curious about how to make a decision. This double matching happens quite often with the customers and loyalty cards (ID here). They can put different spelling but same ID or same person applies for a second card.

Comment: See my answer, I think it'll make you see clearer

Comment: maybe one way to put it is that you want the solution that minimizes the number of ids ? but I believe it will require a whole different level of complexity, so maybe you should explain what you want to do with this result, there might be a better way to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not well defined, here are 2 solutions that satisfy your criteria, but none of them looks like your desired output:

```
library(data.table)

data <- setDT(data.frame(name=c(NA, "bob1", "bob", "jack", "bob1", "bob"), ID=c(1,1,4,3,2,1)))    
data <- na.omit(data) # remove NAs
data$ID <- data$ID[match(data$name,data$name)] # harmonize ids
data$name <- data$name[match(data$ID,data$ID)] # harmonize names
data
#    name ID
# 1: bob1  1
# 2:  bob  4
# 3: jack  3
# 4: bob1  1
# 5:  bob  4


data <- setDT(data.frame(name=c(NA, "bob1", "bob", "jack", "bob1", "bob"), ID=c(1,1,4,3,2,1)))
data <- na.omit(data) # remove NAs
data$name <- data$name[match(data$ID,data$ID)] # harmonize names
data$ID <- data$ID[match(data$name,data$name)] # harmonize ids
data
#    name ID
# 1: bob1  1
# 2:  bob  4
# 3: jack  3
# 4: bob1  1
# 5: bob1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `mapply` and `order`. The `data.table` was not doing anything particular, hence I preferred to just use `data.frame`.

```
data <- data.frame(name=c(NA, "bob1", "bob", "jack", "bob1", "bob"), 
                   ID=c(1,1,4,3,2,1), stringsAsFactors =  FALSE)

# First order on ID
data[order(data$ID),]

as.data.frame(t(mapply(function(x,y){
  data[which(!is.na(data$name) & ((!is.na(y) & y==data$name) | x == data$ID))[1],]

}, data$ID, data$name)))

#   name ID
# 1 bob1  1
# 2 bob1  1
# 3 bob1  1
# 4 bob1  1
# 5 jack  3
# 6 bob1  1
```